# why do python imghdr test functions take the file as an argument?

Tags: python, python-2.7, imghdr

I was looking through the source code for the `imghdr` module, which is part of the python standard library (I use 2.7). The structure is pretty simple—a `what` function that iterates over a list of functions with names like `test_filetype`, and if the passed in file matches any of the tests, it returns the string for that filetype.

All of the `test_filetype` functions take two arguments, `h` and `f`. `h` is a string with the contents of `f.read(32)`, and `f` is the open file object. None of the `test_filetype` functions actually use `f` for anything.

Why would the set of `test_filetype` functions all take an argument that is never used?

Comment: Presumably because it might become necessary to use it for some image formats (or was in the past), and all of the functions in `tests` need to have a consistent interface.

Comment: I glanced at old revisions, and I don't think it was necessary in the past. Is it common to write a set of functions like this and include an extra argument for all of them with the thought that it is possible that argument will be necessary?

Comment: I suppose you could, although it does seem to be a breach of YAGNI. Unless you can find someone who wrote it, I don't see how you'd get a definitive answer.

Comment: GvR made the initial commit in which the precedent for the `test_filetype` functions was established. You're right on the "definitive" part, but I was hoping someone might better understand the thinking, since "it might be necessary in the future" didn't seem that compelling a reason to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that this is to allow for custom functions to be added to `imghdr.tests` . From the [documentation of `imghdr` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html) -

> You can extend the list of file types `imghdr` can recognize by appending to this variable:
>
> `imghdr.test`
>
> A list of functions performing the individual tests. Each function takes two arguments: the byte-stream and an open file-like object. When what() is called with a byte-stream, the file-like object will be None.
>
> The test function should return a string describing the image type if the test succeeded, or None if it failed.

As can be seen from documentation, the `imghdr` module allows extension to the `tests` list. I think the addition argument `f` could be there for these custom functions that are added to this list.

Taking a look at the [`imghdr.what()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/imghdr.py#l9) -

```
if h is None:
    if isinstance(file, basestring):
        f = open(file, 'rb')
        h = f.read(32)
    else:
        location = file.tell()
        h = file.read(32)
        file.seek(location)
```

As can be seen, when we send in a filename to `what()` function, it only reads the first 32 bytes from the file and only sends those 32 bytes in the `h` argument of the `test` function , I believe the additional `f` argument maybe for cases where the first `32` bytes are not enough to determine the image format (especially for custom tests).

Comment: Ah. I had not noticed in the online docs that one is encouraged to extend the `tests`. I can somewhat better understand the added flexibility in the event that a user is writing new tests.